GStreamer 1.24 Python bindings are blacklisted
I am trying to install Python bindings for GStreamer, but the library is blacklisted. My Dockerfile is below. Everything installs without issue, but the libgstpython.so library is blacklisted. I have tried different Python versions, specifying the Python path, and random keyboard bashing without success.
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# Install Python
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.18
WORKDIR /opt
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev wget curl build-essential libssl-dev openssl vim && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar xzvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    ./configure --enable-shared && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# # Install FFmpeg, GStreamer, and reqs for custom plugins
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y \
    ffmpeg \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
    libhdf5-dev \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
    gstreamer1.0-libav \
    gstreamer1.0-tools \
    gstreamer1.0-x \
    gstreamer1.0-alsa \
    gstreamer1.0-gl \
    gstreamer1.0-gtk3 \
    gstreamer1.0-qt5 \
    gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio \
    graphviz \
    python3-gi \
    python3-gst-1.0 \
    libgirepository1.0-dev \
    cmake \
    python-gi-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    ninja-build \
    git \
    flex \
    bison

# # NOTE: pygobject 3.47.0 introduced a bug
# # https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/3353
WORKDIR /opt
RUN pip install pycairo pygobject==3.46.0 meson pipenv
RUN GSTREAMER_VERSION=$(gst-launch-1.0 --version | grep version | tr -s ' ' '\n' | tail -1) \
    && export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 \
    && git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer.git \
    && cd gstreamer \
    && git checkout $GSTREAMER_VERSION \
    && cd subprojects/gst-python \
    && PREFIX=$(dirname $(dirname $(which python))) \
    && meson setup --prefix=$PREFIX builddir \
    && ninja -C builddir \
    && meson install -C builddir

# Install other dependencies
ENV GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0

This is the output from gst-inspect-1.0:
# gst-inspect-1.0 -b
Blacklisted files:
  libgstpython.so

Total count: 1 blacklisted file

EDIT:
The same thing happens when installing apt install gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader rather than building the library from source.
EDIT:
The output of GST_DEBUG=4 gst-inspect-1.0 libgstpython.so is in this gist. The full output was too long to include in the post, but the line that stood out to me is 492:
** (gst-plugin-scanner:15): CRITICAL **: 18:14:35.880: gi.repository.Gst is no dict


Could libgstpython.so happen to have the wrong permissions, or be built for the wrong architecture?

It has permissions -rwxr-xr-x whereas the other plugins are -rw-r--r--. It has the same architecture as the others, though with the debug info stripped.

Related: What is the meaning of blacklisted in gstreamer? -- you'll find guidance on how to debug therein, and should amend this question with details from following those steps.

(run GST_DEBUG=4 gst-inspect-1.0 /path/to/libgstpython.so, of course replacing /path/to with the actual directory name in which that file exists, and [edit] the output into your question).

The error is being thrown here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-python/plugin/gstpythonplugin.c

Here's a couple ideas that could help:

Related to an answer here that Charles included in their response, GStreamer could be trying to load plugins before all python dependencies for custom plugins have been installed. If there's a race condition, removing the GStreamer cache directory @ ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/ then reloading plugins with gst-inspect-1.0 -b should help eliminite this possibility.
Your GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable may need to be updated to something like GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0. Additionally, you should verify that the PYTHONPATH and LB_LIBRARY_PATH env variables are set correctly: PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages & LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib. (Source)

